Plot datetime data as just month not month-year
I have a data frame that looks like this:
structure(list(date = structure(c(1592611200, 1624665600, 1626480000, 
1620086400, 1624147200, 1624752000, 1626566400, 1.566e+09, 1621036800, 
1651536000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    location = c("POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", 
    "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", 
    "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER", "POTOMAC RIVER"), avg_temp = c(70.875, 
    83.075, 92.025, 82.6, 87.8, 87.45, 82.15, 89.6, 75.125, 67.85
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

When I use this code to plot it:
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=avg_temp, color = location)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Average Weigh in Time (F)") +
  xlab("Day") 

It looks like this:

How do i code ggplot so that it removes the year and only plots data in different years just by the month like this:


No the data is truncated to just June through September, sorry I should have mentioned that

Add scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b") to the plot you have.

One option is to switch x-axis to Day of the Year:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = lubridate::yday(date), y = avg_temp, color = location)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Average Weigh in Time (F)") +
  xlab("Day of the Year") 


Or fix the year for all dates, as suggested by Jon in comments:
ggplot(df, aes(x = lubridate::`year<-`(date, 2000), y = avg_temp, color = location)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Average Weigh in Time (F)") +
  xlab("Day") 


Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.1.0

ggplot2 has layers

"scale_x_date for objects of class "Date";
scale_x_datetime for objects of class "POSIXct".

Both allow for customized axis breaks and labels with date_breaks and date_labels, respectively.
Since your column date is a date and time column, you must use scale_x_datetime.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=avg_temp, color = location)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Average Weigh in Time (F)") +
  xlab("Day") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))


Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.1.0
